# How to replace string in java

Tags: java, string, replace

I have the following code

```
String rplaceString="John = Max and Jing => Sira then nothing";
String replaced=rplaceString.replace("=", "==").replace("=>", "=>");
System.out.println("REPLACE STRINF==>>>>>>>>"+replaced);
```

*Expected Output String Like this:*

```
String expectedString="John == Max and Jing => Sira then nothing";
```

If I do above method, Output Looks Like:

> REPLACE STRINF==>>>>>>>>John == Max and Jing ==> Sira then nothing

So, How can replace above string in expected string.

**Edit:** Change String Like this:  **John =Max and Jing => Sira then nothing**

or

**John= Max and Jing =>Sira then nothing**

or

**John=Max and Jing => Sira then nothing**

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: yo don't see, expected output: `John == Max and Jing => Sira then nothing`

Comment: @javanewuser *Remove all the unrelated junk* (that is not part of the expected/actual result) and align the output on top of each-other, and draw focus to the *particular* issue. In doing so you'll probably find out what the problem is.

Comment: You could use replaceFirst() the docs for String methods are here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple way to fix the issue would be to just add spaces around the `=` in your replace:

```
String replaced=rplaceString.replace(" = ", " == ")
```

Then you would only be matching the standalone `=` instead of the arrow as well.

### EDIT:

More comprehensive answer:

```
String s = "John=Max and Jing=>Sira then nothing";

String t = s.replaceAll("(?<=.)=(?!>)"," == ");
t = t.replaceAll("=>", " => ").replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
System.out.println(t);
```

Comment: awesome! great to hear. If you could just accept this answer I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: wait bryan, stackoverflow takes some times for accept answers.

Comment: My bad. shouldn't get so antsy :D

Comment: Bryan, if some change string like this: John =Max and Jing => Sira then nothing ,How to do?

Comment: So let me get this straight, `John =Max and Jing=> Sira then nothing` is the string you want to convert into the expected output `John == Max and Jing => Sira then nothing`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54757/discussion-between-java-new-user-and-bryan).

Answer (score 0):

If a space is always guaranteed after the `=` sign then you can use

```
String replaced=rplaceString.replace("= ", "== ").replace("=>", "=>");
```

Please note that I am appending a space after the `'='` sign as `'= '` while replacing.

Answer (score 0):

```
String rplaceString = "John = Max and Jing => Sira then nothing";
    System.out.println(rplaceString.replaceAll(" = ", " == ").replaceAll("=>", "=>"));
```